# Cannot build on Xamarin Studio Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Remoting

Tags: android, dll, build, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I installed Xamarin and I cannot build the Tasky Solution.

I'm getting this error

Build failed. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

This is .NET Framework issue.  Just uninstall .NET framework from control panel and reinstall it.

Below link suggest that you should repair it but you really should reinstall it.
Also make sure, Xamarin is not open when the installation takes place.

[Source](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/6311).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot unnistall the .Net framework on my windows 8.1 :/

I unnistalled everything that has to be with .Net Framework but it still says that I have a superior version. (4.5)

Comment: ok so you have two options.  Go to control panel, click programs, on the left hand side, click on Turn features on and off. there will be .NET framework there. Uncheck all of them and restart your computer.  IF it's still there, then reinstall the newest .NET framework, and uninstall them in newer to older version.  One of these options should do the trick.

Comment: I did what you said and the problem still exist. I also used the .Net cleanup utility from microsoft to get sure of the elimination.

I could'nt install the .Net framework because my PC still said that it had the .Net Framework installed, so I decided to install all the VS with the framework.

I'm installing VS 2010 - to vs 2013. (I need the IDE's and the .Net frameworks).

Comment: I have a laptop with vs studio 2010 and xamarin runs well on it.

My pc (the one with the problem) has VS 2012 and 2013 (those VS use .Net framework 4.5>)